# Why am I unable to access foreign key information in django templates.

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django app that needs to create XML files to respond to requests. I've go my models setup like this:

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models


class Color(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Colors'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Color: [" + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.name + "] "


class Company(models.Model):
    orders = models.ManyToManyField('Order', through='OrderCompany')
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Companies'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Company:[" + self.orders.__str__() + ", " + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.name + "] "


class ModelColor(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelColors'

    def __str__(self):
        return "ModelColor:[" + self.color + ", " + self.id.__str__() + "] "


class ModelData(models.Model):
    colors = models.ManyToManyField('Color', through='ModelDataColor')
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField('Size', through='ModelDataSize')
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descript = models.CharField(db_column='Descript', max_length=2047, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelData'

    def __str__(self):
        return "ModelData:[" + self.colors.__str__() + ", " + self.sizes.__str__() + ", " + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.name + ", " + self.descript + ", " + "] "


class Modeldatacolor(models.Model):
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelDataColors'
        unique_together = (('model_data', 'color'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Modeldatacolor:[" + self.model_data.__str__() + ", " + self.color.__str__() + "] "


class Modeldatasize(models.Model):
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID', primary_key=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelDataSizes'
        unique_together = (('model_data', 'size'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Modeldatasize:[" + self.model_data.__str__() + ", " + self.size.__str__() + "] "

class Modelsize(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(ModelColor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ColorID')
    size = models.ForeignKey('size', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SizeID')
    amount = models.IntegerField(db_column='Amount')  # Field name made lowercase.
    amountfinished = models.IntegerField(db_column='AmountFinished')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_ModelSizes'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Modelsize:[" + self.color.__str__() + ", " + self.size.__str__() + ", " + self.amount+ ", " + self.amountfinished + "] "


class Model(models.Model):
    model_color = models.ForeignKey(ModelColor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelColorID')
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID')
    model_data = models.ForeignKey(ModelData, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelDataID')
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Models'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Model:[" + self.model_color.__str__() + ", " + self.order.__str__() + ", " + self.model_data.__str__() + ", " + self.id.__str__() + "] "


class Ordercompany(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='OrderID', primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CompanyID')
    stage_number = models.IntegerField(db_column='StageNumber')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_OrderCompanies'
        unique_together = (('order', 'company'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Ordercompany:[" + self.order.__str__() + ", " + self.company.__str__() + ", " + self.stage_number + "] "

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ordertimestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='OrderTimeStamp', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    finishtimestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='FinishTimeStamp', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    confirmed = models.IntegerField(db_column='Confirmed')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Orders'

    def __str__(self):
        self.ordertimestamp = "None"
        self.finishtimestamp = "None"
        return "Order:[" + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.ordertimestamp + ", " + self.finishtimestamp + ", " + self.name + ", " + self.confirmed.__str__() + "] "

class Size(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Data_Sizes'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Size: [" + self.id.__str__() + ", " + self.name + "] "
```

and I call create the template like this:

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('orders/responseTemplate.xml')
    company = Company.objects.get(id=10)  # remember to use `get` for a single item
    order_list = company.orders.all()
    tpcontext = {'orderList': order_list}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(tpcontext, request))
```

the template file I'm using looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    {% for order in orderList %}
    <order id="{{ order.id }}">
        <models>
        {% for model in order.model_set.all %}
        <model id="{{ model.id }}">
            <name>{{model.model_data.name}}</name>
            {% for color in model.model_color_set.all %}
            <color name="'{{color.color.name}}'">
                {% for size in color.modelsize_set.all %}
                <sizeAmount name="'{{size.size.name}}'">{{size.amount}}</sizeAmount>
                {% endfor%}
            </color>
            {% endfor%}
        </model>
        {% endfor %}
        </models>
    </order>
    {% endfor %}
</orders>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get nformation about a certain company (in this case the company with ID number 10) and obtain all of it's orders. After that for each order I want to obtain a list of models. After I have a list of models I want to show the model name on the screen and then I want to iterate through the list of colors associated with each model and add it to the model in the XML file. finally each color has a few size fields which should be added to their respective color. The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>

    <order id="16">
        <models>

        <model id="17">
            <name>Pants</name>

        </model>

        <model id="18">
            <name>Pants</name>

        </model>

        </models>
    </order>

</orders>
```

as you can see I'm able to get a list o models and also the model's name. however the colors don't show up in the list. I've checked that there is information in the database and the information is present.

I think there is an error in this line in the template:

```
{% for color in model.model_color_set.all %}
```

however I don't know what that error can be?

Comment: Is there any reason you are specifying a Model's color through the ModelColor model? Why not directly link Model to Color via a foreign key? This would make what you're trying to do a lot easier.

Comment: So I'm working with a database that's not only used by this django application. Inf fact there are a lot more colomns in each table that I don't really care about. in my particular django project it indeed does not make sense to use all of these fields as I'll never really use them so that's why it might look a bit wierd

Comment: Got it — see my answer below. Does that fix things?

Comment: no it doesn't. could it be that it has to do with the fact that the field has a `_` sign in it? maybe django doesn't like that?

Comment: Got it. Is your color specified directly via foreign key in your Model? Or is it linked through the ModelData model? If the latter, it'll be a different solution and I'm happy to give it some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a one-to-one relationship between Model and ModelColor, so using a set doesn't make sense.

It looks like what you may be trying to access is the Colors set of the ModelData model. You could do that like so:

```
{% for model in order.model_set.all %}
    <model id="{{ model.id }}">
    <name>{{model.model_data.name}}</name>
    Colors:
    {% for color in model.model_data.colors_set.all %}
        {{ color.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work either. (also tried with the answer provided by py_dude)

Comment: OK I've to wait untill I get back to work later this week! will let you know then.

Comment: UPDATE: noe the names of the colors also show up however, I'm unable to show the "sizeAmount" field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `model.modelcolor_set.all` ?
Django doesn't add an underscore when converting the `CamelCase` model name to lower case.

Comment: Inside the `Model` model (confusing right) the fields is called `model_color` so I assumed it would just left it in there. I've tried it though and it doesn't seem to work. Also tried to removed the `_set` part as suggested by sam

Answer (score 1):

Your model defines a ForeignKey from Model to ModelColor. That means that each model only has one modelcolor. There is no `_set` here, and nothing to iterate through; you can follow the foreign key to get the *single* color for that model. You can use the `with` tag to make this slightly easier to work with.

```
    <model id="{{ model.id }}">
        <name>{{model.model_data.name}}</name>
        {% with model.model_color as color %}
        <color name="'{{color.color.name}}'">
            {% for size in color.modelsize_set.all %}
            <sizeAmount name="'{{size.size.name}}'">{{size.amount}}</sizeAmount>
            {% endfor%}
        </color>
        {% endwith %}
```